# Can't format SSD during installation

Tags: system-installation, storage, mandriva

Last night I tried to install Mandriva Linux on PC, where I have already Windows 7. In PC I've got 2 128GB SSD and 1 2TB HDD. On one SSD I installed Win7, and when I select the other empty SSD for installation, I couldn't format it. I get this message:

```
ext4 formatting of sdb1 failed
```

I don't remember what version on linux I tried to install. Is where a problem to have 2 operating systems on 2 different hard drives, and have option to choose which OS I want to run? How should I format empty SSD to install Linux on it?

Comment: Try to obtain a more detailed error message from one of the virtual consoles.

Comment: thx for reply, but I dont know how to do it. I'm not too good in linux.

Comment: try pressing ctrl-alt-f1 (f2, ... etc.) when the error occurs, one of the virtual consoles usually contain a list of errors.